# A button that will add a textbox below another textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

My form code

```markup
<form>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Artist/s:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="artists"><input type="button" value="add"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

How can I add another textbox below or right after my first textbox by clicking the add button?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Just add another cell.  3 tds.  Make an attempt as it will answer 10 questions for you.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ereWW/)

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnId');
    btn.onclick = function(){
        var txt = document.createElement("textarea"); 
        btn.parentNode.insertBefore(txt, btn);
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: where should i put that? newbie here

Comment: @AeronNicoReyesMiro I modified my code copy it and paste it any where in side your html page(inside body or head tag).